# Team Foundation Server for two developers

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are two developers with MSDN subscriptions (each one with his own subscription). For one of our client, we would like to use TFS for source code repository, bug tracking, ... We are using mainly VS2010 solutions. I'm a bit lost with all the different licences.

What do we have (to buy?) to have TFS installed for our needs?

Comment: What version of studio and MSDN subscription do you currently have?

Comment: Each MSDN subscription one full production server license of the full TFS server.  You can also potentially try http://tfspreview.com if you want it hosted & managed by Microsoft.

Comment: I use VS2010 and I have MSDN Professional subscription.

Answer (score 6):

[**TFS Express 2012**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251396) is what you need.

From version 2012 (currently available in pre-release RC1), it is free for 5 developers. It is also scalable as your team grows and want to move to an higher license level.

I'm working with the TFS Express 2012 RC, upgraded from the TFS 11 Express Beta  released in February and can confirm it is very stable and supports working with Visual Studio 2010 and [2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251391) side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

> What do we have (to buy?) to have TFS installed for our needs?

Providing you intend to run the data and application tiers on a single Windows instance (in which case the TFS CALs in your subscriptions cover an instance of SQL Server Standard<sup>1</sup>).

Then you need the Server 2008 or 2008 R2 licence for two users, and the two CALs. That server could provide AD, DNS, ... services which will make sharing resources easier.

However TFS can be installed on client OSs: in which case I don't think any further licences are needed.

(The background here: MSDN licence includes OS licences for testing and development of applications/products, not general usage. Unlike the single per subscription, at Universal level, Office which can be used beyond development and testing of applications; or the VS instances.)

On the other hand: MSDN licensing is not simple, take time to read the documentation and MSDN licence (which overrides the individual product licences included).

---

<sup>1</sup> Either 2008 or 2008R2 (MSDN licence rules were updated to cover both); but check the edition (working from memory here).

Comment: You said I need only Server 2008 or 2008 R2 + 2 CALs. I understand the 2 CALs are used to allows 2 people to acces TFS from their VS solutions. BUT What must be installed on the Server 2008? Do I need to install specific software on this server to have TFS up and running? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that was Windows Server CALSs (you have the TFS CALs in MSDN subs). Once you have 2k8 running follow the (latest) TFS installation instructions (linked on MSDN): there are quite a lot of details especially if you want reporting/SharePoint (I'm not assuming you don't want them).